# Xilinx device specific primitives

Tags: vhdl, verilog, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I need a list of device-specific primitives of Xilinx devices. I know that ISE has a list of templates and there are also PDF user guides but I need them as list of files in a folder so that I can parse them and extract name and port-list of every module.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Xilinx ISE take a look at the folder "C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\src\unisims\primitive" (default install location, version may vary).
In this folder you will find VHDL files for all Xilinx primitives, not sorted by device however.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful. Wish there was a way to categorize them according to devices. (BTW I upvoted your answer but it didn't apply because of my reputation...)

Comment: @Laleh you could always mark this answer as correct

Comment: @scary_jeff Sure I will do. But I am still waiting for more answers because this is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the file named **unisim_VCOMP.vhd**.  It has all the component declarations of the Xilinx primitives.

For ISE, this is located at

> [install dir]\[version]\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\src\unisims

For Vivado,

> [install dir]\[version]\data\vhdl\src\unisims

Note, for Vivado, if you have VHDL that has primitives from older devices, then use **unisim_retarget_VCOMP.vhd**, which retargets old primitives to 7 Series and Ultrascale equivalents.  However, there are some cases when retargeting certain primitives is not possible.

If your code is for 7 Series and Ultrascale families, I wouldn't worry about the "retarget" file.

Comment: Thanks. The one you mentioned lists component of all modules in a single file which is somehow more convenient for me to parse. But still no device info.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost found what I wanted. Language templates are stored in location:

> [install dir][version]\ISE_DS\ISE\data\projnav\templates